# Filter JSON object value

Tags: ios, json, swift

I want to take only the city and country in the object value of employee address, here is the JSON

```
[
    {
        "VacancyTitle": "PHP Engineer",
        "VacancyJobType": "Full Time",
        "EmployerCompanyName": "Vodafone",
        "EmployerCompanyLogo": "d022813eadb769c3a972221621552d04.jpg",
        "EmployerAddress": "10th Floor, Aitken Spence Tower 2, 315, Vauxhall Street, Colombo 02, Sri Lanka.ty",
        "UserID": "144",
        "block_count": "0"
    }
]
```

I just want the value of " Colombo 02, Sri Lanka " How can i do this ?

Comment: Try using the a string.Split method then acces the array returned and get the values from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let s="10th Floor, Aitken Spence Tower 2, 315, Vauxhall Street, Colombo 02, Sri Lanka.ty"
       let v = s.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
       let stringYouNeed = v[v.count-2]+","+v[v.count-1]
       print(stringYouNeed)
```

To get json-object you can use SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 1):

in Swfit 2.0 Xcode 7 beta 5. YOu can do the following:

```
let array = [["VacancyTitle": "PHP Engineer","VacancyJobType": "Full Time",
"EmployerCompanyName": "Vodafone",
"EmployerCompanyLogo": "d022813eadb769c3a972221621552d04.jpg",
"EmployerAddress": "10th Floor, Aitken Spence Tower 2, 315, Vauxhall Street, Colombo 02, Sri Lanka.ty",
"UserID": "144",
"block_count": "0"
]]

let mapResult = array.map { $0["EmployerAddress"] }

let employerAddress = mapResult[0]!

let components = employerAddress.characters.split{$0 == ","}.map{String($0)}

let count = components.count
let finalString = components[count - 2] + ", " + components[count - 1] //" Colombo 02,  Sri Lanka.ty"
```

Xcode 6.4 Swift 1.2 :

```
let array = [["VacancyTitle": "PHP Engineer","VacancyJobType": "Full Time",
"EmployerCompanyName": "Vodafone",
"EmployerCompanyLogo": "d022813eadb769c3a972221621552d04.jpg",
"EmployerAddress": "10th Floor, Aitken Spence Tower 2, 315, Vauxhall Street, Colombo 02, Sri Lanka.ty",
"UserID": "144",
"block_count": "0"
]]

let mapResult = array.map { $0["EmployerAddress"] }

let employerAddress = mapResult[0]!

let components =  split(employerAddress) {$0 == ","}
let count = components.count
let finalString = (components[count - 2] + ", " + components[count - 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        //parse the json data
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                             options:kNilOptions
                                                               error:&error];//you will get response data from server url or local json

        NSArray *addressValue = [json valueForKey:@"EmployerAddress"];

        NSString* cityName = [[[addressValue componentsJoinedByString:@","] componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:4];
        NSString* countryName = [[[addressValue componentsJoinedByString:@","] componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:5];

        //here is your output
        NSLog(@"City name = %@", cityName);//Colombo 02
        NSLog(@"Country name = %@", countryName);//Sri Lanka.ty
```